# No option for already commented on for Low Quality Posts

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

While reviewing Low Quality Posts queue, I come across this situation very often when a post is low quality but someone has already gone in before me and left a comment saying this post needs a more detailed answer or something similar. Something like this post maybe

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19249637

Wouldn't it be good if there was another option like 'Already Taken Care Of' apart from the usual categories like Looks Ok, Edit, Recommended Deletion, and Skip! That way we could remove the post from this queue and bring it down. To me it doesn't make sense to leave another comment for improvisation on the Answer when somebody has already done so, and none other options feel suitable.

Comment: Even better, should upvoting the comment suffice?

Comment: Is it possible you've gotten the Low Quality Posts and First Posts queues mixed up? "Already Taken Care Of" doesn't make sense as an option for Low Quality Posts.

Comment: If you choose the same comment as an existing one it's not going to be added.

Comment: @BSMP I haven't got anything mixed up. On a Low Quality Post, people are supposed to leave a comment for OP to make it better. All I am saying is what if somebody has already left that comment.

Comment: @Neels No, you're not commenting so that people can fix it.  If you're suggesting that an answer be deleted, you're doing so because the answer is beyond help.  The comment is there so that the author knows what they did wrong, why their answer was deleted, and what to not do in the future.  An answer that says, "I have this problem too" is not salvageable.  It just needs to be deleted.  The comment is merely there so that the author knows not to post comments saying "me too" in the future.

Answer (score 3):

That post doesn't merit deletion, so the appropriate course of action is to choose "looks okay".  That *is* the option you've described (the post doesn't merit deletion, and doesn't belong in this queue anymore).

(Note that this would be different if it were, say, the first posts queue, which is there to do more than just decide if the post merits deletion.  In that queue other actions would be merited.  In this queue you're *only* expected to determine if the answer merits deletion, hence those are the options given to you.)

Comment: Me and 3 other people disagree with you, the only one who agrees looks like a robo reviewer, can you please explain why you think that post shouldn't have been deleted?

Comment: @Oleg: Because if the error was indeed caused by a missing reference to gdk-sharp identified by the use of a class specific to that library, then there really isn't much more to be said than "add the missing reference". Anything else, screenshots, sample code (how do you include sample code for this other than by including the actual .csproj markup, which realistically no one ever edits directly), etc is just extra baggage for a self-explanatory instruction. If it turns out that the answer is wrong, then it should be downvoted, not deleted.

Comment: @Oleg So why don't you think it's an answer to the question?  Is it asking for clarification from the author of the question?  Is it saying that they have the same problem?  Is it asking a new question?  Or is it actually an attempt to answer the question?  You're the one claiming that the post isn't an answer.  Why don't you think it's an attempt to answer the question?

Comment: @Servy To me the post doesn't still Looks Ok, because the OP has not given enough information on it and it doesn't stand for deletion as well because he/she might add more information in future.

Comment: @Neels "I think this answer should have more detail" is not a reason to delete an answer.  If you think that the answer is not useful because it's missing information that you feel is necessary, you're more than welcome to downvote it.  But from the perspective of the review queue, "looks okay" means, "this post does not meet any of the criteria for deletion", and this post doesn't meet any of the criteria for deletion.  If you see problems with the post that merit some action other than deletion, you can leave the queue and perform them.

Comment: @BoltClock It can't be caused by a missing reference to gdk-sharp because gdk-sharp **is referenced** `-pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0`, there is also no reason to think that it's caused by that because the errors are about something different. The rest of the answer is of similar quality, gdk.color has nothing to do with the errors. Servy - It should be deleted because no attempt was made to answer the question.

Comment: Of *course* an attempt was made to answer the question. It's right there. You can't delete something that's not there, @Oleg. Presumably you didn't answer Servy's questions because you can't truthfully answer "yes" to any of them, which makes this squarely an attempt at an answer. Which brings us back to the last sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: @Oleg If you think that it's an incorrect answer to the question then *downvote it*.  That doesn't make it not an answer.  Your explanation for why *the answer* was wrong definitively shows that it *is* an answer.  If it wasn't even an answer then you couldn't possibly argue that it's wrong.  The fact that the only thing you can say for why it's not an answer is that it's wrong, *proves* that it's an answer.

Comment: @BoltClock /Servy what about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19263068 I can't answer yes to any of them either, was that post supposed to stay?

Comment: @Oleg Flag that as rude or offensive.  Don't flag that as not an answer.  (It's true that it's not an attempt to answer the question, but "offensive" is the most applicable flag).  Note that of course that post *was* deleted for being offensive, it *wasn't* deleted for being a non-answer.

Comment: @Servy: Done now.

Comment: @BoltClock Do you really think this made SO better? (I understand your and Servy's arguments, I just think exceptions should be made for something of sufficiently low quality or the rules need to be changed)

Comment: @Oleg Do you really want moderators, or a handful of users with no expertise in the subjects and a few hundred rep being the ones to make judgements about the technical merits and correctness of an answer, and being expected to delete content based on those technical judgements that they are entirely unqualified to make?  Do you trust the people with 250 rep to be able to accurately determine that all of your posts are correct, and not to mistakenly think that one of them is wrong due to a lack of expertise in the subject matter?  That's why questions of correctness are left to votes.

Comment: @Oleg: I think the net effect is negligible either way.

Comment: Servy - Yes, I want moderators to make judgements. @BoltClock That's true, probably like the outcome of most meta arguments.

Comment: @Oleg So *how* do you expect them to make judgements over things that they have no expertise, and are entirely unqualified to determine the correctness of?  And why should that one person's, or those few people's, judgement completely overrule the entire rest of the community of people who *are* subject matter experts and who *can* accurately determine the post's correctness' ability to judge the post?

Comment: @Servy I'm sure that any moderator on SO is fully capable of realizing that that answer is complete crap. It's not just one person, it was deleted by 4 people (and before that flagged) and moderators are not just some random people, they're established and trusted longtime SO members.

Comment: @Oleg How can you expect a moderator to know whether or not the problem that the OP is facing is actually due to a missing reference or not?  How are you expecting them to determine whether the OP has actually demonstrated that they've added the reference, showing the answer to be wrong?  The fact that 4 people voted to delete what is *very clearly* an answer to the question by claiming it's not an attempt to answer the question doesn't help your point, it hurts it.  If 4+ people honestly can't even tell *that* it's an answer, how could they possibly judge if it's technically correct or not.

Comment: @Servy In this case I explained it to him. I don't see the relevance between the ability to judge what is and isn't an answer and the ability to tell that it's not correct. The former requires profound knowledge about SO rules, the later requires very very basic programming skills (in this case).

Comment: @Oleg So you think that moderators should delete answers because one person told them that it's wrong and all moderators should just trust every user that tells them that an answer is wrong and immediately, unilaterally, an irrevocably delete it?  You're not concerned in the slightest that someone might have been incorrect in telling a mod that it's wrong, or worse still, falsely claim that an answer is wrong just to get it deleted?  The system to judge the correctness/usefulness of an answer is up and down votes.  If you think the answer is wrong, downvote it.  Don't claim it's not an answer.

Comment: Like I said, moderators are programmers and are capable of making their own conclusions, no trust is required. If they received an explanation, understood it and agreed with it, I think it's better to leave a crappy answer deleted than undelete it even if it should be undeleted when you completely follow the rules to the letter.

Comment: @Oleg The moderators are skilled enough programmers to know that they're not qualified to be the sole arbiter of the correctness of every single post on the network, all by themselves.  They know themselves well enough to know that they cannot accurately judge the correctness and quality of all, or even most, posts, and that the small handful of them simply can't possibly evaluate every single post out there.  There are millions of answers, and just a few dozen mods.  The numbers just don't work.

Comment: The site's founders knew this when they created the site, that's why they created the voting system for people to provide their feedback on the quality of posts, rather than expecting a few moderators to be the ones to judge them.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your specific example, 'Already Taken Care Of' doesn't make sense as an option for Low Quality Posts because a post that's been taken care of in that queue has either been deleted, edited, or gotten enough Looks OK votes to leave the queue. It wouldn't be in the queue at all if it's been taken care of.

> On a Low Quality Post, people are supposed to leave a comment for OP to make it better. All I am saying is what if somebody has already left that comment.

If you want to Recommend Deletion but don't want to leave a comment, just select "No comment needed" at the top of the dialog.

> To me the post doesn't still Looks Ok, because the OP has not given enough information on it

All "Looks OK" means in the Low Quality Posts queue is that the answer post is an actual attempt to answer. It doesn't mean that it's a good answer or even a correct answer.